# How to use data URI to deliver MSWord document (.docx) to Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ms-word, data-uri

I have a JavaScript app that does client-side encryption & decryption of files, storing the encrypted data at Google Cloud Storage.  All the encryption & data transfer stuff works correctly, but I'm having trouble getting all document types to open in Chrome.  PDF works fine because of Chrome's built-in PDF viewer, but I would like to have it auto-open other file types as well.  For example:

JavaScript app retrieves encrypted data, then decrypts it to produce a String or ByteArray containing a Word document.

I create a data URI and call window.open() on it.  In the PDF case, a new tab opens with the PDF document.  When the data URI is a Word document (MIME type application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document) I get a blank window with (apparently) no content.

I have been able to create an <A> tag with the data URI, and it downloads the correct data if the user right-clicks the link, but although I've set that MIME type to auto-open upon download, Chrome doesn't open it.  (It does auto-open Word docs sent from a regular HTTP request with that MIME type.)

I would like to do several things with my decrypted data, starting with it in a client-side JavaScript string:

- Open in a new tab/window (for things that the browser can do, or has a plugin for)
- Open in external application
- Save as file

Any help on these?

Thanks!

Comment: did you find a solution for this one?

Comment: I haven't worked on this project for several years; I don't remember how far I got.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It will need that Google Chrome also have a MS Word viewer as well. Something that is not included by default like the PDF viewer...

Comment: I can't expect (or wait for) Chrome to include viewers for every possible document type.  Firefox seems to just pass newly-downloaded items off to the operating system to find some program that can open them.  It would be great if I could get at least that functionality out of Chrome.  But for now, it appears to do much less: either nothing (discarding the data) or no more than storing it in a file, and you can't even provide a default name for the file!